# windows disk partitions are not coming up while downloading popos in a uefi bios system

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, installation, pop-os

So I finally decided to download Linux and chose popos for the purpose.

I had already turned off the secure boot but my SSD and its partitions are not showing up while trying to install it only the USB drive is there
I searched about it at the various website but didn't get it to work
Please help

- Photo of installation where no partitions are there:

[image]

+Picture if disk partitions in windows

[image]

Secure Boot And Fast Boot already disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening wrong here was that I didn't change the disk mode to AHCI
In order for this to work you need to go to boot menu and change the disk mode to AHCI.
By the way in mine's the setting was hidden and by pressing Ctrl+S it appeared there.
But the problem is that most probably after changing the drive mode your windows will not boot.
In that case you need to make the window use AHCI.
However, I just Went for a Clean Install.